# PHP echo message

Tags: php

I am creating a online store Website at the moment I am working on Basket which is working.  I am trying to add a functionality which will echo a message once a user clicks the add button confirming that the item indeed has been added to basket.

I created a simple if statement that i believe should take care of this nicely but nothing is happening. No message is echoed.

code:

```
if (isset($_GET['add'])){
    $quantity = mysql_query('SELECT product_id, product_qua FROM products WHERE product_id='.$_GET['add']);
    while($quantity_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($quantity)){
        if($quantity_row['product_qua'] !=$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]){
            $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+='1'; 
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['add'])){
    $basketMessage = "Item Sucesfully Added To Your Basket";
    echo $basketMessage;
}
```

Any suggestions...?

ANSWER:

OK forget the above code........

the belov code is code form a file where products are listed and then linked to cart.php the slice of code above:

code:

```
while($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
    ?>
        <table id='display'>
        <tr><td><?php echo "<img src=$get_row[$product_image] class='grow'>" ?></td></tr>

        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th><strong>Avalible</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Price</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Description</strong></th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td width='290px'><?php echo "$get_row[$product_name]" ?></td>
        <td width='290px'><?php echo "$get_row[$product_qua]" ?></td>
        <td width='290px'><?php echo "&pound $get_row[$product_price]" ?></td>
        <td width='290px'><?php echo "$get_row[$product_des]" ?></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo '<a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['product_id'].'" onclick="return basketMessage()">Add</a>';?></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

    <?php
        }
    }

    ?>

<script>    
function basketMessage(){
      var confirmed = confirm("Add this item to Basket ?");
      return confirmed;
}
</script>
```

OK as you can all see form the code I am looping the products database and listing some items that are assigned with the ADD button.....Now i added some javascript to this button to inform the user if this is the item they want to add to their basket

Comment: PHP finishes executing when the web page is sent to the user. Javascript starts executing when the user receives the web page. So anything that happens after the web page is generated (client side scripting) needs to be in Javascript.

Comment: You need to sanitize the GET variable before using it in a database query. Not doing so will cause nasty problems for your online store.

Comment: ... and to do that, you should look into `mysql_real_escape_string()`, or, much better, [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Comment: Thx for the answers guys........But am quiet sure i can just echo out a message i have done this many times but in this instance it does not work, ye javascript is another solution but echo should work or print...

Comment: @Tomazi, you should try isolating the issue. Does the message show if you comment out the rest of the file?

Comment: Ps.....this store will not go on line am a PHP learner and though a on Line store would be a good practice...all the MySql injections and POD or mysqli am not worried about will implement these after i complete the shop and i am 99.9% done all i want is this Message :D

Comment: OK people I took a different approach......looking at the suggestions i implemented some javascript and it works.....Now I am going to edit my question to show what and how i have done it, because I implemented this changes in another file DO NOT GO CRAZY saying that i perhaps should of showed code from the file as well :) But as a result of some answers I had a decent idea THX

Comment: I will be upvoting the answers that pushed me into this direction but not sure if i should accept any due to the fact that the answers are not direct :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @patashu stated, this is not possible with PHP alone.  You should add javascript that handles the adding of the item to your cart via AJAX, then listens for the response you've echoed back and if it was successful, display the success message.

this could be a starting point:

html:

```
<button class="mybutton">add to cart</button>
```

javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.mybutton').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url:"yourscript.php", 
        data: {stuff: 'your cart data', productid: 134}
        success: function(data){
          alert("your success message'); 
        }
      }); 
    }); 

    }); 
    </script>
```

PHP function that is listening for your ajax call:

```
//does stuff 
$basketMessage = "Item Sucesfully Added To Your Basket";
echo json_encode($basketMessage);
```

obviously this is not complete...this is really just a starting off point / a general idea of what you should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible in php without resend the whole page. You could use javascript to react on some button click events.

In combination with jQuery this results in something like this

```
<div id="messagefield"></div>
<button id="buttonid">click me!</button>
<script>
    $("#buttonid").click(function() {
        $("#messagefield").html("The button was clicked");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have an error at this line:

```
$quantity = mysql_query('SELECT product_id, product_qua FROM products WHERE product_id='.$_GET['add']);
```

if must be

```
$add = $_GET['add'];
$quantity = mysql_query("SELECT product_id, product_qua FROM products WHERE product_id='$add'");
```

or

```
$quantity = mysql_query("SELECT product_id, product_qua FROM products WHERE product_id='".$_GET['add']."'");
```

And you don't have to use mysql_* any more cause is deprecated.
You can use http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: And what about his question?

Comment: Thx for your answer But i cant see why would my initial query would be wrong it works fine.......?

Answer (score -1):

Why are you doing it in two phases? Try this:

```
if (isset($_GET['add'])){
$quantity = mysql_query('SELECT product_id, product_qua FROM products WHERE product_id='.$_GET['add']);
while($quantity_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($quantity)){
                if($quantity_row['product_qua'] !=$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]){
                    $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+='1'; 
  }
}
$basketMessage = "Item Sucesfully Added To Your Basket";
echo $basketMessage;
}
```

Comment: i tried this it didnt work that why i tried doing this in two parts